# Custom Headers for $resource - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-resource

Hi I am new to Angular JS, I am trying to put custom header in my $resource method, but I am not sure how would I do that
Following is my code :

```
function userFactory($resource, API) {
    return $resource(API + '/users/:cmd', {}, {}, {
            login: {method: 'GET', params: {cmd: 'current'}, headers: headerParam},
            get: {method: 'GET'},
            create: {method: 'POST'}
        }
    );
```

I would like to add a custom header 'headerParam' based on which user has logged in since the header would contain username and password specific details.

Answer (score 0):

As I look at the header documentation in [$http.config](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage). This is map of string\ function, which implies you can call a function to set specific header

Something like

`headers:{credentials: getUserCredentials}`

And in the factory you can create the above method.

```
var getUserCredentials = function(config) {
}
```

I have not tried, see if it helps.